# Try gcc without installing it

Tags: linux, gcc

I built gcc 9.3.0 from source and want to test it with some simple examples. However, I'd like to keep the gcc installation on my Ubuntu 18.04 system intact. Ideally, I'd just open a console with environment variables ready for g++.

Is there a simple way to achieve that? Some posts tell of "module" but I don't have such a tool.

Regards

To be more specific: I called configure and make, but not make install.

```
../gcc-9.3.0/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu-18.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++ --program-suffix=-9.2 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-gtk-cairo --with-arch-directory=amd64 --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch

make -j12
```

I can't find a g++ binary in the build directory anywhere, only xg++ which produces the error output.

Comment: Outside of your machine:  Just go to the (amazing !!) Compiler Explorer:  https://godbolt.org/   On your machine:  on _current_ Ubuntu I have four different gcc releases (7 to 10) and several clang ones.  And there is Docker...

Comment: You don't need any environment variables. Use a full path to the compiler, and read about `-Wl,-rpath` command line argument

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  To be more specific: I did configure and make but not make install. I added libc includes via -I compiler option but g++ complains it can't find liblto_plugin.so. Trying to add it with -l or -L did not help.

Comment: `docker run -ti gcc:9.3` . `To be more specific` Please be _way_ more specific. Please post the exact steps that you did, please post the exact commands that you executed and please include the exact error message that you are getting. Please add `-v` option to  `g++`  call and post the verbose output with the error message. What exactly `-l` `-L` options did you try? Please kindly post. Are you asking how to try gcc without installing (i.e. with godbolt for example), or are you asking how to try your compilation of gcc on your computer without installing it?

Comment: @KamilCuk The latter. I added the config and make command to the original post. Well, technically I didn't have to build it myself I just need gcc 9.3 to try something. So I built it from source assuming that just building it would leave the environment intact.

Comment: `technically I didn't have to build it myself I just need gcc 9.3` install docker and `docker run -ti gcc9:3`

Comment: @KamilCuk Will this only copy gcc to the disk or make it default compiler too?

Comment: This will run a container with gcc v9.3 in it. It will not edit your system in any way. Technically, it will download and copy a whole system with gcc installed in it and run it.

Comment: You should have configured it to install somewhere under your home directory (.`/configure --prefix=/home/somewhere/here`) and then do make install. It makes your life much easier.

Comment: And no libdir or bindir!

Comment: Desperado17 : You can have as many versions of `gcc, g++` as you want, installed at the same time. Example "other extra gcc" https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing

Comment: I opted for the docker method. @KamilCuk Would you mind turning this into an answer so I can give you the hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker has taken the industry like a storm. To use `gcc:9.3`, just install and run docker and do:

```
docker run -ti gcc9.3
```

You'll get a shell with gcc9.3 installed. For more information, see docker documentation.